# How to tell the current 'write position' of a Boost Circular Buffer to enable accessing a previously stored value

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

I want to access a value in a `Boost Circular Buffer` that is, for example, 5 positions 'in the past'.  So, imagine I am now writing a value '7' to a previous stream of integers:

3, 5, 6, 9, 2, 8, 6

Therefore I have now:

7, 3, 5, 6, 9, 2, 8, 6

I want the '2' since that is 5 positions in the past.  How do I get that?

In other words, what is the current 'write index'?

I think that I might need to use `boost::circular_buffer<double>::const_iterator` but I'm not sure.

Comment: You mean like `cb[cb.size() - 5]`?

Comment: @Barry Well, I hope that works.  It sounds logical if size is giving the current 'size' modulo capacity and is not the same as capacity since the buffer may be full already - if that makes any sense?

Comment: Size and Capacity are only different on the first cycle of the Circular Buffer, otherwise it would be that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but your worries about modulo indexing seem overly anxious to me. The whole purpose of a circular buffer *abstraction* is to hide the index arithmetics from the caller, if you ask me.

I'd be thoroughly disappointed in the library design if Boost would let this implementation detail leak out¹

Here's a simple demo that seems to be what you want:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/380fc4f6e4bea81a)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(10); // [tag:cb-so-fixedsize] obviously

    for (int msg : { 3, 5, 6, 9, 2, 8, 6, 7 }) {
        cb.push_back(msg);
    }

    // should be 2
    std::cout << "t0-5: " << cb[4] << "\n";
    std::cout << "t0-5: " << *std::next(cb.begin(), 4) << "\n";

    // should be 9
    std::cout << "t0-5: " << cb[3] << "\n";
    std::cout << "t0-5: " << *std::next(cb.begin(), 3) << "\n";

    while (!cb.empty()) {
        std::cout << cb.front() << " ";
        cb.pop_front();
    }
}
```

Prints

```
t0-5: 2
t0-5: 2
t0-5: 9
t0-5: 9
3 5 6 9 2 8 6 7
```

¹ I'm well aware that the implementation detail is implied by the name "circular", but hey. Many data structures in the standard library and alike have slightly confusing names

Comment: Thanks! This project uses C++ 98 so I can't do std::next but I in fact need something like `*std::prev(cb.end(), 4)`.  If I can get something like that working then I'll accept your answer

Comment: `std::cout << "t0-5: " << *boost::prior(circularBuffer.end(), 4) << "\n";` does the trick.  I'll accept your answer since you got me 95% of the way there... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only viable answer is for you to keep track of the index yourself. According to the Boost documentation, it appears that the container has a fixed allocation size and works similar to a stack.

Like other containers, elements do not intrinsically keep track of their key. Therefore, it is up to you to externally keep track of any properties like position or key. It appears that you only have the usual `std::vector`-like functions available to you: `size()`, `capacity()`, `at()`, `operator[]`, and such, including the iterator functions.

I suppose that the best thing you can do is to find out some way of keeping track of the "keys" or index numbers. Since the circular buffer simply loops around and rewrites over the first array on "overflow," perhaps you could keep a count yourself with a modulo function.

Comment: Your idea is a good one and was going to be my next course of action if I couldn't find an easier solution.  However, sehe pointed me to a solution using `boost::prior`.  Thanks